# What is the difference between using reset! and a new def to change the value of a variable associated to an atom in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, reset

According to Clojure's documentation, `reset!` can be used as:

> Sets the value of atom to newval without regard for the current value.
> Returns newval.

Thus, I can do:

```lisp
user> (def my-test (atom 666))
#'user/my-test
user> my-test
#<Atom@66d7a880: 666>
user> @my-test
666
user> (reset! my-test 77)
77
user> my-test
#<Atom@66d7a880: 77>
user> @my-test
77
```

But, is there any difference between using **another** `def` instead of `reset!`?

```lisp
user> (def my-test (atom 666))
#'user/my-test
user> my-test
#<Atom@66d7a880: 666>
user> @my-test
666
user> (reset! my-test 77)
77
user> my-test
#<Atom@66d7a880: 77>
user> @my-test
77

;;;; converting it back to the original value via def

user> (def my-test (atom 666))
#'user/my-test
user> @my-test
666
user> my-test
#<Atom@7ce4f432: 666>
user>
```

Just by reading the experiments on the REPL I **cannot** identify any difference. But I am new to Clojure, so I am probably naive here.

If there is any difference, why should I use `reset!` instead of a **new** `def`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the answer in the REPL output in your question. When you write `(reset! a 1)`, you give a new value to the existing atom. When you write `(def a (atom 1))`, you get a brand new atom. Why does this matter? Because someone may have another reference to the old atom: in the former case they see the new value, and in the latter case they don't. Compare, for example:

```
(def a (atom 0))
(defn counter [c] (fn [] (swap! c inc)))
(def count-up (counter a))

(count-up) ; 1
(count-up) ; 2
(reset! a 0)
(count-up) ; 1 again
```

with

```
(def a (atom 0))
(defn counter [c] (fn [] (swap! c inc)))
(def count-up (counter a))

(count-up) ; 1
(count-up) ; 2
(def a (atom 0))
(count-up) ; 3, because the old atom still holds 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Changes to [atoms](https://clojure.org/reference/atoms)  are always free of race conditions. New-def-ing is not.

Answer (score 2):

A Clojure `Var` is meant to be a global value that, in general, never changes (as always, there are exceptions to every rule). As an example, function declarations are normally stored in a `Var`.

A Clojure `Atom` is meant to point to a value that can change. An atom may be held in a global Var or a local variable binding (e.g. in a `(let ...)` form). Atoms are thread-safe (this is one of their primary purposes).

If you are just playing around with experimental code with only one thread, you can do a lot of sloppy or dangerous stuff and there is no problem. However, you should learn how to use each tool for its intended purpose.

---

### More detailed discussion:

- [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/zombie-metaphysics/)
- Book [Getting Clojure](https://pragprog.com/titles/roclojure/getting-clojure/)
- Clojure.org - [Vars](https://clojure.org/reference/vars)
- Clojure.org - [Atoms](https://clojure.org/reference/atoms)
- clojuredocs.org - [atom](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/atom)
- [Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet)

Comment: This is all true, but I don't see it answering the question.

Comment: The question seemed to be more about intended usage than a specific example. Until the OP reads the details of Var & Atom, he won't be able to understand a detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

`def` creates a new atom (means allocate new memory space for an atom - setting it up - setting a pointer), while `reset!` just resets an existing atom (just changing value in the cell the pointer points to).
Therefore it is logical that `reset!` must be much cheaper (faster execution and less usage of resources) than `def` which you can test by:

```
(def n 10000000)

(time (dotimes [_ n] (def a (atom 1))))
## "Elapsed time: 2294.676443 msecs"


(def b (atom 1))
(time (dotimes [_ n] (reset! b 1)))
## "Elapsed time: 106.03302 msecs"
```

So `reset!` is one magnitude of order faster than `def`.

Comment: You're right that it's slower, but not because it's allocating a new atom. That is pretty cheap. Most of the expense in your example is in setting up a new var. You can see this by timing `(def a 1)` instead - it takes around the same amount of time as `(def a (atom 1))`.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks - yes - I mean't with 'setting it up' the generation of a new thing. De novo assignment. But you are right, it seems that generating a de novo variable per se is the costly part, not the generation of an atom compared to a variable. Thank you for pointing this out!